# Joining phrases with prepositions

Tags: sentence-construction

If I have to say the following idea,

> 1. I am pleased to submit our manuscript entitled “ABC” for consideration of publication in PQR Journal.
> 2. I wish to submit this manuscript under the theme issue of XYZ.

in a complete sentence, is the following construct acceptable?

> I am pleased to submit our manuscript entitled “ABC” for consideration
>   of publication in PQR Journal *under* the theme issue of XYZ.

I am in doubt because I've omitted the clauses.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your complete sentence bears the complete meaning, it should not be a problem. However, there are some mistakes which I cleared in the modified sentence.

> I am pleased to submit our manuscript entitled “ABC” for consideration of publication in PQR Journal having the theme issue on XY.

*Having* sounds more natural than *under* to me. Also as a preposition, I would prefer *with* to *under* in this case. Again, a **theme** happens *on* a subject, not *of* a subject.

**EDIT** - [StoneyB's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6062/joining-phrases-with-prepositions#comment9190_6064) seems to be quite a handy here. As you can see, there are still some modifications that should be done to make it sound more natural. So get rid of superfluous terms/phrases like "entitled","consideration for publication","theme issue on XY" etc. and to make it the simplest construction, change it to, as prescribed,

> ....  to be considered for publication in the XY issue of PQR Journal.

Comment: + Some things that would make it even better: **1)** *Entitled* is superfluous. **2)** We generally submit or consider an article **for** publication. **3)** *Consideration* is superfluous and jingles badly with *publication*; cut it, or at the very least change it to *to be considered for publication*; **4)** *Theme issue on XY* is redundant, and the article is being submitted for publication in that issue of the Journal; * I'd suggest something like "to be considered for publication in the XY issue of *PQR Journal*.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you for your excellent comment. I always thought there is something still there not quite right and you pointed them.